# Spectrum of Harmonic Oscillator with Ladder Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, differentiation

Is the ladder operator trick specific to the harmonic oscillator or can it be generalized to arbitrary second order operators? If yes, what is the general mathematical theory behind it? Can all Hermitian second-order operators be split into a product of two first-order operators?

Comment: What is a second order operator?

Comment: [People continue to write new stuff](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08581) on the Schrödinger-Dirac-Infled-Hull (SDIH) [factorisation methods and more.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9812003) I first learnt about this in a QM textbook by Ohanian.

Comment: In how many spatial dimensions? A 1D polynomial can be factorized. But generically not in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Qmechanic that's kind of part of my question.

Comment: As I know, you can also use ladder operator for Poschl-Teller potential.

Comment: Are you familiar with the derivation of the spectrum of an angular momentum operator?